# Google Maps Marker Show/hide

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I tried several codes and searched a lot for an answer, but I can't get this to work. I know very little of Javascript, so i'm hopping someone can help me with this, cause i'm losing my mind with this. The markers are not toggling, just nothing happens.

```
     var customIcons = {
  monumento: {
    icon: 'images/monumento_ico.png'
  },
  hotel: {
    icon: 'images/hotel_ico.png'
  },
  restaurantes: {
    icon: 'images/restaurante_ico.png'
  },
  museus: {
    icon: 'images/museu_ico.png'
  }
};

var markerGroups = { "museus": [], "monumentos": [], "restaurantes": [], "hotel": []};
var gmarkers = [];

function load() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.639104, -8.210413),
zoom: 12,
mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
});
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;



map.set('styles', [
{
zoomControl: false,
},
{
featureType: "road.highway",
elementType: "geometry.fill",
stylers: [
  { color: "#ffd986" }
]
},{
featureType: "road.arterial",
elementType: "geometry.fill",
stylers: [
  { color: "#9e574f" }
]
},{
featureType: "road.local",
elementType: "geometry.fill",
stylers: [
  { color: "#d0cbc0" },
  { weight: 1.1 }

]
}, {
featureType: 'road',
elementType: 'labels',
stylers: [
  { saturation: -100 }
]
}, {
featureType: 'landscape',
elementType: 'geometry',
stylers: [
  { hue: '#ffff00' },
  { gamma: 1.4 },
  { saturation: 82 },
  { lightness: 96 }
]
}, {
featureType: 'poi.school',
elementType: 'geometry',
stylers: [
  { hue: '#fff700' },
  { lightness: -15 },
  { saturation: 99 }
]
}
]);

downloadUrl("markers.xml",  function(data) {
var xml = data.responseXML;
var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");

var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
map: map,
position: point,
icon: icon.icon,
shadow: icon.shadow,
type: type
});

bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
}
});
}

function createMarker(point, name, address, type) {
var marker = new GMarker(point, customIcons[type]);
markerGroups[type].push(marker);
var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
});
return marker;
}

function toggleGroup(type) {
  for (var i = 0; i < markerGroups[type].length; i++) {
    var marker = markerGroups[type][i];
    if (marker.isHidden()) {
      marker.show();
    } else {
      marker.hide();
    }
  } 
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
infoWindow.setContent(html);
infoWindow.open(map, marker);

});
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
new XMLHttpRequest;

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (request.readyState == 4) {
request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
callback(request, request.status);
}
};

request.open('GET', url, true);
request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="map_wrap">
<div class="siderbarmap">
<ul>
<input id="monumentoCheckbox" type="checkbox" onclick="toggleGroup('monumento')">
<input id="museusCheckbox" type="checkbox" onclick="toggleGroup('museus')">
<input id="restaurantesCheckbox" type="checkbox" onclick="toggleGroup('restaurantes')">
<input id="hotelCheckbox" type="checkbox" onclick="toggleGroup('hotel')">


</ul>

</div>

<div id="map" style="width:100%;height:585px; z-index: 1;"></div>
```

This is the XML
Thank you so much for any help you can give!

```
<markers>
<marker name="Castelo" address="Rua da Condessa de Valença" lat="38.64351973190569" lng="-8.216521812152905" type="monumento" />
<marker name="Anta 1 de Tourais" address="Estrada Nacional 114" lat="38.64260059929888" lng="-8.159376865959189" type="monumento" />


<marker name="Hotel da Ameira" address="Herdade da Ameira" lat="38.64109640475479" lng="-8.180432206726096" type="hotel" />
<marker name="Hotel Montemor" address="Avenida Gago Coutinho 8, 7050-248 Montemor-o-Novo" lat="38.64925541964039" lng="-8.216489625644726" type="hotel" />

<marker name="Restaurante Monte Alentejano" address="Av. Gago Coutinho 8" lat="38.6492329" lng="-8.216665" type="restaurantes" />
<marker name="Restaurante A Ribeira" address="Rua de São Domingos" lat="38.6347498199708" lng="-8.206468892765088" type="restaurantes" />

<marker name="Núcleo Museológico do Convento de S. Domingos" address="" lat="38.643139" lng="-8.212732" type="museus" />
<marker name="Centro Interpretativo do Castelo de Montemor-o-Novo" address="Rua Condessa de Valença" lat="38.64258748216167" lng="-8.21467108793263" type="museus" />


</markers>
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YEPB7/6/)

You need to look at the javascript console.

- fixed createMarker to use v3 syntax and used it.
- initialized arrays in markerGroups[type]
- there is no `.isHidden` method for a [google.maps.Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) it is .getVisible.
- there are no .show() or .hide() methods for a [google.maps.Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker), it is .setVisible.
- there are no marker shadows in v3 since the implementation of the "visual refresh"

(can't test your custom markers, you didn't provide them)

**working code snippet:**

```js
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var customIcons = {
  monumento: {
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png'
  },
  hotel: {
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png'
  },
  restaurantes: {
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow.png'
  },
  museus: {
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/purple.png'
  }
};

var markerGroups = {
  "museus": [],
  "monumentos": [],
  "restaurantes": [],
  "hotel": []
};

function load() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.639104, -8.210413),
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();



  map.set('styles', [{
    zoomControl: false
  }, {
    featureType: "road.highway",
    elementType: "geometry.fill",
    stylers: [{
      color: "#ffd986"
    }]
  }, {
    featureType: "road.arterial",
    elementType: "geometry.fill",
    stylers: [{
      color: "#9e574f"
    }]
  }, {
    featureType: "road.local",
    elementType: "geometry.fill",
    stylers: [{
        color: "#d0cbc0"
      }, {
        weight: 1.1
      }

    ]
  }, {
    featureType: 'road',
    elementType: 'labels',
    stylers: [{
      saturation: -100
    }]
  }, {
    featureType: 'landscape',
    elementType: 'geometry',
    stylers: [{
      hue: '#ffff00'
    }, {
      gamma: 1.4
    }, {
      saturation: 82
    }, {
      lightness: 96
    }]
  }, {
    featureType: 'poi.school',
    elementType: 'geometry',
    stylers: [{
      hue: '#fff700'
    }, {
      lightness: -15
    }, {
      saturation: 99
    }]
  }]);

  //         downloadUrl("markers.xml", function (data) {
  var xml = xmlParse(xmlData);
  // var xml = data.responseXML;
  var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
    var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
    var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");

    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
      parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
      parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
    var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
    // var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
    var marker = createMarker(point, name, address, type, map);
    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
  }
  // });
}

function createMarker(point, name, address, type, map) {
  var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: point,
    icon: icon.icon,
    // shadow: icon.shadow,
    type: type
  });
  if (!markerGroups[type]) markerGroups[type] = [];
  markerGroups[type].push(marker);
  var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
  bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
  return marker;
}

function toggleGroup(type) {
  for (var i = 0; i < markerGroups[type].length; i++) {
    var marker = markerGroups[type][i];
    if (!marker.getVisible()) {
      marker.setVisible(true);
    } else {
      marker.setVisible(false);
    }
  }
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);

  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', load);

var xmlData = '<markers><marker name="Castelo" address="Rua da Condessa de Valença" lat="38.64351973190569" lng="-8.216521812152905" type="monumento" /><marker name="Anta 1 de Tourais" address="Estrada Nacional 114" lat="38.64260059929888" lng="-8.159376865959189" type="monumento" /><marker name="Hotel da Ameira" address="Herdade da Ameira" lat="38.64109640475479" lng="-8.180432206726096" type="hotel" /><marker name="Hotel Montemor" address="Avenida Gago Coutinho 8, 7050-248 Montemor-o-Novo" lat="38.64925541964039" lng="-8.216489625644726" type="hotel" /><marker name="Restaurante Monte Alentejano" address="Av. Gago Coutinho 8" lat="38.6492329" lng="-8.216665" type="restaurantes" /><marker name="Restaurante A Ribeira" address="Rua de São Domingos" lat="38.6347498199708" lng="-8.206468892765088" type="restaurantes" /><marker name="Núcleo Museológico do Convento de S. Domingos" address="" lat="38.643139" lng="-8.212732" type="museus" /><marker name="Centro Interpretativo do Castelo de Montemor-o-Novo" address="Rua Condessa de Valença" lat="38.64258748216167" lng="-8.21467108793263" type="museus" /></markers>';

function xmlParse(str) {
  if (typeof ActiveXObject != 'undefined' && typeof GetObject != 'undefined') {
    var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
    doc.loadXML(str);
    return doc;
  }

  if (typeof DOMParser != 'undefined') {
    return (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
  }

  return createElement('div', null);
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map,
#map_wrap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div class="map_wrap">
  <div class="siderbarmap">
    <ul>
      Monuments (blue)
      <input id="monumentoCheckbox" type="checkbox" onclick="toggleGroup('monumento')" checked="checked" />Museums (purple)
      <input id="museusCheckbox" type="checkbox" onclick="toggleGroup('museus')" checked="checked" />Restaurants (yellow)
      <input id="restaurantesCheckbox" type="checkbox" onclick="toggleGroup('restaurantes')" checked="checked" />Hotels (green)
      <input id="hotelCheckbox" type="checkbox" onclick="toggleGroup('hotel')" checked="checked" />
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="map" style="width:100%;height:585px; z-index: 1;"></div>
</div>
```