# Google Map Marker Exit Requires Two Clicks

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have been working with the example fiddle listed toward the bottom of the post below and noticed an issue I can not solve. The Google Map is created with markers and click of any marker pops up the info window as it should. The issue I am having is it appears to actually create two instances of the info window when the user clicks on the marker, which requires the user to click on the X twice to close the info window.

Any suggestions to fix this problem would be greatly appreciated.

[Google Maps Marker Show/hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24844915/google-maps-marker-show-hide/24846077#24846077)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring infoWindow twice.

line 14: `var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();`

line 43: `var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();`

just remove 'var' on line 43: `infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();`

Here is your Fiddle working: http://jsfiddle.net/YEPB7/28/

Comment: interesting.  As you posted your suggestion I also found another solution.  The following line is also called twice 116 and 133... if I comment out 116 it works also.   bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);

Comment: reason for the down vote?

Comment: don´t know, i tought your question was legit

Comment: me either.... wasn't my original code, wasn't my fiddle, found it, liked it, found an error.  JS is not my strength by any stretch of the imagination... but down voting without anything.... gutless turds!